# What's the purpose of key in Realtime database in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The key is shown in the figure. Why do we need these keys? Can we create a database without using these keys?
[image: key highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key like the `-N4D...` in your screenshot is generated when you call `push()`. Such keys are not requires, as you can also call `set()` to write data without generating the key. But these so-called push keys are a convenient way to generate ever-increasing keys automatically for chronological lists of data.

Also see these classic Firebase blog posts:

- [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.blog/posts/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68)
- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).